# My codeigniter hyper links are not working properly?

Tags: php, codeigniter

my hyper links are not working properly...please check the link

localhost/classified/ad_shop-member/admin_main/admin_main/admin_main/admin_main/admin_main/admin_main/product_list

whenever i am clicking again and again on the same link then address bar show the same link..

```
<ul class="box">
        <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="admin_main"><span>Add Product</span></a></li> <!-- Active -->
        <li><a href="admin_main/product_list"><span>Product List</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>My Orders</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Add Advertisement</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Add Banners</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `/` at the start of your link `href=""` parts so that it looks for more of a "base" directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the application base_url in config.php file? You have to first set the base url for your application in that file and then use it in the href tag as:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin_main/product_list"><span>Product List</span></a></li>
```

Also remember to autoload url helper in autoload.php to be able to use base_url.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check out the url helper (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin_main');?>"><span>Add Product</span></a></li>
```

This is assuming that your base url is set correctly in application/config/config.php